# Set which pulseaudio sink is affected by volume control buttons

Tags: pulseaudio, pavucontrol

On my previous installation of ubuntu 10.04 it was possible to set a sink in pavucontrol, which is affected by the volume up-/down buttons on my keyboard. Now in Lubuntu 11.10 this does not work anymore. I can check the green tick, but this affects nothing, still always one and the same sink is affected.

Did anybody have this before? Where is this function configured - is there a config file, in which I could change this configuration directly?

Comment: [This Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90547/how-to-configure-hardware-volume-control-buttons-on-a-dell-inspiron-9400) provides a dirty work around, which might be applicable for you too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you most likely are experiencing a bug.

If you are not experiencing a bug, notice that switching the default output sink with pavucontrol will only affect programs you start -after- the change has been made. It will not affect programs that are already running.

To affect programs you already have running, each one will need to be switched individually under the pavucontrol "Playback" tab.

Your pulse-audio configuration files are stored under ~/.pulse/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `pacmd list-sinks` and `pacmd set-default-sink`. There's a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback) related to this